# Why doesn't this return the rotations of the given number?

Tags: python

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do with an example:

```
Number = ["1","9","7"]
```

So I want it to return:

```
[["1","9","7"],["9","7","1"],["7","1","9"]]
```

What I get is:

```
[["7","1","9"],["7","1","9"],["7","1","9"]]
```

For some obscure reason it replaces my first results with the last one.

```
def Get_Rotations(Number):
    Rotations = []
    x = 0
    while x < len(Number):
        Number.insert(0,Number.pop())
        Rotations.append(Number)
        x += 1
    print(Rotations)
    return Rotations
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create copies of `Number`. You are manipulating the same list in each iteration and append that list three times to `Rotations`. Therefor you see three times `Number` in it's "end state".

```
Rotations.append(list(Number))
```

That minor change should do the trick! ;-)

Comment: It does indeed, ty! But I don't understand why your solution works :s Why do you state use list on Number which already is a list?

Comment: list(...) is used to create a copy of `Number`. It's not used as type conversion! Otherwise you would just add a reference to `Number`. I would propose that you do the `print(Rotations)` inside the `while` loop. The output will probably make everything clear to you in the split of a second. ;-)

Comment: `from copy import copy ... Rotations.append(copy(Number))` is much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to suggest completely different solution.

```
from collections import deque

number = ['1', '9', '7']

rotator = deque(number)
rotations = [number]

for _i in range(len(number) - 1):
    rotator.rotate()
    rotations += [list(rotator)]

print(rotations)
```

Note that this solution is much more efficient.

Also you may or may not want to have `rotator` to be in the initial state after this code block run. Than you may edit this code into following

```
from collections import deque

number = ['1', '9', '7']

rotator = deque(number)
rotations = []

for _i in range(len(number)):
    rotations += [list(rotator)]
    rotator.rotate()

print(rotations)
```

Now `rotator` will be in initial `number` state. The code is a little easier to understand but you've got +1 cycle in `for`.

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing `Rotations.append(Number)`, you're not copying `Number`, you're adding a reference to `Number`. All three of the indices in `Rotations` are pointing to the same object (basically like `Rotations = [Number, Number, Number]`), so changing Number will affect all three outputs.

Instead, create a new array, fill it with the contents of `Number`, and add it to `Rotations`.

Answer (score 0):

First Let me give you the correct answer

```
def Get_Rotations(Number):
    Rotations = []
    x = 0
    while len(Number):
        Rotations.append(Number.pop())
    print(Rotations)
    return Rotations

>>> Number = ["1","9","7"]
>>> Get_Rotations(Number)
['7', '9', '1']
['7', '9', '1']
```

Now in your case, you were doing few things wrong

1. You were popping the Number and always inserting at the beginning.
2. Inserting a List within a List

Do you know you can do this in a much easier way?

```
Number[::-1]

>>> Number[::-1]
['7', '9', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why you code doesn't work are very well explained in the other answers.

I want to point one more thing.

Insertions at the beginning of the list are quite costly. You use them here `Number.insert(0,...)` They [have](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) `O(n)` complexity (appendings are actually `O(1)`).

Bellow I'll show another way to do the same thing using iterators which just loop over the list with some shifts:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def rotate(L):
    ln = len(L)
    it = cycle(iter(L)) #create an overall iterator
    for _ in range(ln): #there are len(L) output lists
        yield list(islice(it,3)) #slice next 3 elements, for a list and yield the rusult
        it.next() #skip one element to start a new list shifted by one
```

`rotate` is a generator which is used to create an iterator which will yield the needed lists.

`cycle` and `islice` is from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

Example of usage:

```
for el in rotate(Number):
    print el
```

Output:

```
['1', '9', '7']
['9', '7', '1']
['7', '1', '9']
```

Or just using list constructor:

```
print(list(rotate(Number)))
```

Output:

```
[['1', '9', '7'], ['9', '7', '1'], ['7', '1', '9']]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be:

```
number = ["1","9","7"]

def get_rotations(num):
    rotations = []
    for i in range(len(num)):
        rotations.append(list(num[i:] + num[0:i]))  
    return rotations
```

You could also use an integer instead of list of stringified integers. For example:

```
number = 197

def get_rotations(num):
    string_num = str(num)
    rotations = []
for i in range(len(string_num)):
    rotations.append(int(string_num[i:] + string_num[0:i])) 
    return rotations
```

This would give:

```
[197, 971, 719]
```

And it takes a much shorter time to execute.